BroadcastReceiver onReceive not triggering with AlarmManager setExact
My application is meant to send a notification after a certain interval, but the onReceive is not being triggered in my BroadcastReceiver when I use AlarmManager. I have stripped the code back to find the problem but am not having any luck. The setExact doesn't seem to be key as I have tried just set and setExactAndAllowWhileIdle.
NotificationService
    public void notification(Context context){
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("CHANNEL_1", "CHANNEL_NAME", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("CHANNEL_DESC");

        NotificationManagerCompat nm = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        nm.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            if(!alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()){
                return;
            }
        }
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent();
        alarmIntent.putExtra("titleExtra", "Title");
        alarmIntent.putExtra("textExtra", "Text");
        alarmIntent.setAction("TEST_ACTION");
        //context.sendBroadcast(alarmIntent);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Scheduled for 5 seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

MyBroadcastReceiver
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("ON RECEIVE");

        String message = intent.getStringExtra("textExtra");
        String title = intent.getStringExtra("titleExtra");
        Notification notification;

        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "CHANNEL_1")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(1234, notification);
    }

AndroidManifest.xml
        <receiver
            android:name=".services.NotificationService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="TEST_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

When the commented out context.sendBroadcast is uncommented, the onReceive is hit and the notification is sent, so I don't think the issue is with the onReceive, nor with the notification part of the situation as it doesn't get to the onReceive at all when not working.
However if I add (context, MainMenuActivity.class) to the Intent creations
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, MainMenuActivity.class); then the sendBroadcast also does not work. I don't know if that is related or a separate issue though.
I also tried creating and registering the receiver programmatically but it behaved the same.
Also have tried with the enabled=true not included and with exported=false and same behaviour.
Happy to add more code or context

Try alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
+ 5000, pendingIntent);

thanks, I should have said but that was what I originally started with, I changed to using the Calendar after seeing other examples using it, but no change
